# View shifting up

Tags: ios, swift3, uiscrollview

I have a `ViewController` in which there is a `ScrollView` and a View inside the `ScrollView`. The View consist of multiple `TextFields`. Also there is a `NavigationContoller`. When i click on a `TextField` and again click back on the screen the keyboard disappears but the View is shifted up and some textfields hide. Please help me how to solve this

This is my code:

```
class EODViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var views: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var inc50: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var out50: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var dec50: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var savebutton: UIButton!

var activeField: UITextField?
let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.custom)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navigationItem.title = "Before EOD"

    //For Back button task
    self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true

    //to dismiss keyboard on click anywhere on screen
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)

    // to get keyboard notifications
    registerForKeyboardNotifications()

    //textfield delegates
    self.inc50.delegate = self
    self.out50.delegate = self
    self.end50.delegate = self
    self.dec50.delegate = self

}


override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    let allowedCharacters = CharacterSet.decimalDigits
    let characterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: string)
    return allowedCharacters.isSuperset(of: characterSet)

}
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {

    self.out50.resignFirstResponder()
    self.end50.resignFirstResponder()
    self.str50.resignFirstResponder()
    self.inc50.resignFirstResponder()
    self.dec50.resignFirstResponder()

    if textField == self.out50 {

        if self.out50.text?.isEmpty ?? true
        {
            self.out50.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Enter Value", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.red])
            return false
        }
        if end50.isUserInteractionEnabled == false
        {
            if checkValue(textvalue: out50, deno: 50, errorText: error50) == false
            {
                return false
            }
            if error50.text != "Enter multiple of 50"
            {
            editProcessBeforeoneOut(str: str50, inc: inc50, dec: dec50, out: out50, end: end50,terror: error50)
            self.out100.becomeFirstResponder()
            }
        }
        else{
        self.end50.becomeFirstResponder()
        if error50.isHidden == false
        {
        }
        }
    }
    if textField == self.str50
    {
        if self.str50.text?.isEmpty ?? true
        {
            self.str50.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Enter Value", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.red])
            return false
        }
       if checkValue(textvalue: str50, deno: 50, errorText: error50) == false
       {
        self.str50.becomeFirstResponder()
        return false
        }
        if error50.text != "Enter multiple of 50"
        {
            editProcessBeforeoneOut(str: str50, inc: inc50, dec: dec50, out: out50, end: end50,terror: error50)
        self.inc50.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }
    if textField == self.inc50
    {
        if self.inc50.text?.isEmpty ?? true
        {
            self.inc50.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Enter Value", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.red])
            return false
        }
        if checkValue(textvalue: str50, deno: 50, errorText: error50) == false
        {
            return false
        }
        if error50.text != "Enter multiple of 50"
        {
            editProcessBeforeoneOut(str: str50, inc: inc50, dec: dec50, out: out50, end: end50,terror: error50)
        self.dec50.becomeFirstResponder()
        }
    }


    return true
}

func validate() -> Bool
{
    var valid : Bool = true
    if self.str50.text?.isEmpty ?? true
    {
        str50.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Enter value", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.red])
        valid = false
    }

    return valid

}


func registerForKeyboardNotifications(){

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillBeHidden(notification:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

}

func deregisterFromKeyboardNotifications(){
    //Removing notifies on keyboard appearing
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self, name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWasShown(notification: NSNotification){
    //Need to calculate keyboard exact size due to Apple suggestions
    self.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
    var info = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size
    let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize!.height, 0.0)

    self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
    self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

    var aRect : CGRect = self.view.frame
    aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize!.height
    if let activeField = self.activeField {
        if (!aRect.contains(activeField.frame.origin)){
           // self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeField.frame, animated: true)
        }
    }
}

func keyboardWillBeHidden(notification: NSNotification){
    //Once keyboard disappears, restore original positions

    self.view.endEditing(true)
    self.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
}

func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField){
    activeField = textField
      NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(EODViewController.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField){
    activeField = nil
}

func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
}

func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    // Perform your custom actions
    // ...
    // Go back to the previous ViewController
    _ = navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)


}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    button.setTitle("Return", for: UIControlState())
    button.setTitleColor(UIColor.black, for: UIControlState())
    button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 163, width: 106, height: 53)
    button.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = false
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.Done(_:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

}


func keyboardWillShow(_ note : Notification) -> Void{
    DispatchQueue.main.async { () -> Void in
        self.button.isHidden = false

        self.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true

        var info = note.userInfo!
        let keyBoardWindow = UIApplication.shared.windows.last
        self.button.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (keyBoardWindow?.frame.size.height)!-53, width: 106, height: 53)
        keyBoardWindow?.addSubview(self.button)
        keyBoardWindow?.bringSubview(toFront: self.button)
         let keyboardSize = (info[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue.size
        let contentInsets : UIEdgeInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize!.height, 0.0)

        self.scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets
        self.scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets

        var aRect : CGRect = self.view.frame
        aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize!.height
        if let activeField = self.activeField {
            if (!aRect.contains(activeField.frame.origin)){
                self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(activeField.frame, animated: true)
            }
        }


        UIView.animate(withDuration: (((note.userInfo! as NSDictionary).object(forKey: UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey) as AnyObject).doubleValue)!, delay: 0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseIn, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.frame = self.view.frame.offsetBy(dx: 0, dy: 0)
        }, completion: { (complete) -> Void in

        })

    }

}

func Done(_ sender : UIButton){

    DispatchQueue.main.async { () -> Void in

        self.textFieldShouldReturn(self.activeField!)
    }

}

}
```

Comment: provide some screenshot

Comment: Show us your code logic.

Comment: change your concept from ScrollView to uitableview, it is easy to handle

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: @Anbu.karthik I have added code

Comment: @dahiya_boy Code added..please check

Comment: @Priyanka Your question is on hold. so generate reopen. As of now from your code i found that you shifted up your screen in `keyboardWasShown` as contentsize but when keyboard is hides you didn't put it reset content size . For more details show me before and after keyboard open images.

Comment: @dahiya_boy you mean content insets???

Comment: @dahiya_boy The view does not shift whole keyboard size

Comment: @dahiya_boy you are correct i did not resize the size. Thanks i solved the problem

Comment: @Priyanka **Suggestion :** Instead of doing all these stuff.. getting size of keyboard move screen here and there and put them back at actual place blah blah.., you can simply use `https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager` and this pod do all the required stuff for you, so please have a look.

Answer (score 0):

You should try `UITableView` in a `UIViewController`. The `UITableView` automatically manages better than a `UIScrollView`. All your textfields can be put in a `UIView`, which is set to `TableView` header view.

```
let headerView = UIView()
headerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
headerView.height(header_height)
tableView.tableHeaderView = UIView()
tableView.tableHeaderView?.frame.size.height = header_height
tableView.tableHeaderView?.addSubview(headerView)

// set autolayout for headerView to fill the tableView.tableHeaderView here
```

Comment: or use add subview of tableview

Comment: @Anbu.karthik can't add subview to tableView. we can't control the subview. 
Another solution is add every textfield into a cell, static TableView and cell is create before `table:cellForRowAt` called

Comment: I cant use TableView now.. All the design is ready and it would be difficult to change everything

Comment: @Priyanka w/o adding your ui images and core logic, nobody can helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You perhaps want to use `UITableView` instead of `UIScrollView`. There is a very stable library for handling keyboard when there are multiple `UITextFields` in a `UITableView`. Check out [**TPKeyboardAvoiding**](https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding). I have been using this in couple of my apps and it works really great.